# Ember build error that is happening on adding a route that has an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, macos-high-sierra

So here are the details. I'm running the code on a mac. The code was originally built on ubuntu. This wasn't a problem on ember till date.

ERROR -

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   '/Users/...emberapp/tmp/funnel-input_base_path-nz4m8qQr.tmp/index.html'

and below that, this...

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   '/Users/flyn/Documents/working local/backend
>   dashboard/tmp/funnel-input_base_path-xjJozhFY.tmp/index.html'
>       at Error (native)

This is the route that's causing the issue. The ajax call works independently when called on browser when running this:

http://localhost:4300/getRecords?by_param=by_usage&include_docs=true&key_type=%20

This is the code on routes.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({     
    ajax: Ember.inject.service(),   model(){        return 
    this.get("ajax").request("http://localhost:4300/getRecords", {
                data: {
                    "by_param": "by_usage",
                    "key_type": "",
                    "include_docs": true,
                    "key_value": {}
                }
            }).then(function(usr) {
                // return usr.rows.data;
                var ar = []
                for (var i=0; i<usr.rows.length; i++){
                    ar.push(usr.rows[i].doc.data);
                }
                return ar
        });
    } 
});
```

Now here's what I did. I removed the ajax call entirely to see if it works after that. It didn't. Then I did  (in a very similar naming convention for the route name, with a hyphen -) ...

> ember -d route route-name

**now it works. Built the route again, added the ajax. It continues working. Close the server and restart, it stops working.**

Finally, an additional note. 
I saw a similar error on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775953/ember-build-fails-no-such-file-or-directory-lstat-funnel-input-base-path-xxx)

But I already have watchman, which wasn't an issue before, and the first answer (not comment) suggests some ideas, which I'm not sure what that meant. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I add a similar issue, have you tried to [clear the watchman-list](https://gist.github.com/lukemelia/8daa762da7e2bda3df12) ? it helped me (after a restart of the computer or restart of sublime text) all was working well but sometimes the issue was still there.

Comment: (for root in $(watchman watch-list | jq -r '.roots | .[]'); do watchman watch-del "$root" ; done) 
Ran that on /bin/sh
It gave an error
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 7

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jerel/f4d8771de0147f4ead5e
tried that. Didn't help either